# New branch from Master or current Dev branch

Tags: git, branch

We have a Master branch which is current production version of a bigger solution of multiple projects. We also have a Dev1 branch (from Master) where current development is ongoing. When we apply a hotfix to Master it is immediately pulled into Dev1 branch.

Now we need to start a new concurrent development in regards to Master. I'm thinking of creating a new branch Dev2 but I'm not sure where to branch it off, Master or my Dev1 branch?

I know there's at least one common functionality in Dev1 which we will need in Dev2. This of course is not in Master yet. So I'm thinking it would be better to branch from Dev1, will we have problems merging Dev2 into Master later on? Dev1 will finish and merge into Master before Dev2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the best thing is to branch from Dev1. It is difficult to answer whether (or not) you will encounter problems while merging Dev2 into master: it basically depends on how many conflicts you have, that is, on the common parts between the two merging branches.

That said, I suggest you to do the following: when you complete the work on Dev1, merge it both to Master and Dev2.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The more I think about this I think we should branch from Dev1. And further on keep merging Dev1 to Dev2 regularly because they will share functionality which can be changed both in Dev1 and Dev2 - it is our Data Access Layer that is being shared.

Comment: I will accept your answer as this is what I've done eventually. My Dev2 was branched from Dev1.